# Finding size of message sent in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to optimise a serialise function for size, and wanted to compare the size of the message sent across the wire for two different schemes.

Is there a way of checking the size of the socket.io message to be sent for a given object?

Sorry if this is a trivial question/there's an obvious answer...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add the programming language you are trying to do this in? Please tag with the programming language as well.

Comment: I know Chrome can measure the size of each websocket frame or ajax request, and i suppose it's the same for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome's developer tools. A guie is available [here](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/). This excludes the outer headers (i.e., IP and TCP), if you need those as well, you have to use a separate tool like tcpdump or Wireshark.